# Extends with no relation

Tags: java

I have 2 class just call it `Customer` and `Stuff`, `Customer` has attribute(Id,Name,Address along with getter and setter) and `Stuff` class has(Id,Name,Stock along with getter and setter). Based on those class attribute, `Customer` and `Stuff` class has 2 a similar attribute and method(Id,name, getId(),getName() and setId(parameter),setName(parameter)). So I create one abstract class as Base Class that contain(Id,Name,getter and setter) just call it `myBaseClass`, so I just need to extend myBaseClass to my `Customer` and `Stuff` class rather than writing (Id,Name, getter and setter)attribute in each class.

I was thinking there is no problem with what i was create, until my friend tell me that my class should not use inheritance, just write `attribute and method(Id,Name)` on each Customer and Stuff class because, Customer and Stuff class has no relation like Animal and Tiger because Tiger is an animal for example.

Should I still using inheritance or just typing more for `(Id, name,getter and setter)` in each Customer and Stuff Class ?

Comment: Are you using inheritance *just* to avoid having to specify the two properties in both classes? Would you ever want to use `Customer` and `Stuff` in the same context?

Comment: This comes down to a matter of opinion, and so probably isn't a good fit for SO. (If you kept the base class -- which I'm not giving an opinion on -- I'd give it a better name, like `ThingWithIdAndName`.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no "right" answer for this.

Inheritance can be brittle, and in the OO world you should favor Composition over Inheritance.  I would agree with your friend that these two classes are independent and shouldn't share an inheritance hierarchy.

However if you would at some point treat them in a similar way, you could implement a reusable interface if it was needed.

However in this situation - I would not couple these classes together unless there was a business need.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend is right, there is no association between the two classes so creating an abstract class that they both extend shouldn't be done. But I don't agree that you should create a separate attributes class because the attributes class won't have any special methods and will simply just have methods to return and set the values. There is no association between the atrributes of both classes, as far as I know, so I believe that this will be just overdoing it and you should leave it as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

1. If there is a practical need in class named, for example, Person(id, name), then you can use it.
2. If you will not have such cases, then these classes have no any relation between each other and should be separated. I think most of IDEs support code generation by fields specified. More strong example would be Street(id, name), Person(id, name).